PostgreSQL Partial and Parallel Aggregation
I am writing custom aggregation. I have written it in C with internal data type and PL/Pgsql. It seems that aggregate written in C is significantly faster than one written in PL/Pgsql. For me, I would want to write further aggregates in PL/Pgsql because it is more cleaner. Can I speed up the one written in PL/Pgsql?
Also, I am not an expert in writing extensions in PostgreSQL. Does people usually write their extension in C ?
Below is the overview of my aggregates. I run these aggregates on the same table but one written in C is at least 4-5x faster than the other.
CREATE AGGREGATE avg_speed_pgsql(double precision) (
    SFUNC = avg_speed_transfn,
    STYPE = AvgSpeedState,
    FINALFUNC = avg_speed_finalfn,
    COMBINEFUNC = avg_speed_combinefn,
    PARALLEL = safe
);

CREATE AGGREGATE avg_speed_c(float8) (
    SFUNC = avg_transfn,
    STYPE = internal,
    COMBINEFUNC = avg_combinefn,
    FINALFUNC = avg_finalfn,
    SERIALFUNC = avg_serializefn,
    DESERIALFUNC = avg_deserializefn,
    PARALLEL = safe
);


We cannot tell if you can speed up your PL/pgSQL code, because you didn't show it. C will always be much faster, and people use it if speed is important.
